# Audio file transfer over websocket

Tags: android, websocket, audio-streaming, wav, data-transfer

I have a wav file created in android mobile and i want to send this file to server over web socket. am using autobahn lib for web socket connection. Used below code to send the file stream.

```
byte [] buffer  = new byte [1024];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

Log.d(TAG, "Sending...");
boolean status = true;
while (status) {
     int in = fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);                
     if(in != -1){                  
         if(in < buffer.length){                         
             byte[] temp = new byte[in];                        
             for(int i=0; i<in; i++){
                 temp[i] = buffer[i];                           
             }
             mConnection.sendBinaryMessage(temp);
         } else {
             mConnection.sendBinaryMessage(buffer); 
         }                                       
     } else {
         status = false;
     }                  
 }
```

the .wav audio file playing fine in mobile. but in server side the received file is not a proper wav audio file and it is not playing.

server code:

```
public void onMessage(byte[] data, boolean arg1) {                      
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting new recording.");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(f1, true);
        fOut.write(data);
        fOut.close();                                                       
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Please help.........